# Date and Time to only date

Tags: r

I have the following date format

```
2018-02-06T16:50:36Z
```

I am trying to change it to only date format in R using the following however it is not working:

```
date_1 <- data %>% mutate(date_time_submitted = as.Date(date_time_submitted, format = "%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S:%Z"))
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just using the incorrect format as you are missing the `T` character and have an extra `:` character between the day and hour and the seconds and timezone indicator. Changing the format to `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"` gives the correct date:

```
> as.Date("2018-02-06T16:50:36Z", format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
[1] "2018-02-06"
```

Another option would be to use the `as_date`/`as_datetime` function from the `lubridate` package, which give the correct date(time) without specifying the format:

```
> lubridate::as_date("2018-02-06T16:50:36Z")
[1] "2018-02-06"
> lubridate::as_datetime("2018-02-06T16:50:36Z")
[1] "2018-02-06 16:50:36 UTC"
```